# href with parameter not calling controller

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, href

I would like to achieve super basic functionality where I click on something and will be returned with more details of this entry - precisely I **click on movie title** and would like to call a `@controller` that will bring more details of this movie. Currently this is never calling my controller :

```
@GetMapping("/film/{title}")

<td><a href="/film/film.title" th:text="${film.title}">Film</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to include your observations about what does happen when you click on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With little you provide on your question, this should give you what you need.

```
<a th:href="|/film/+${film.title}|" th:text="${film.title}">
```

Comment: hi, thank you for reviewing my question. My line of code is a row of a table with list of movies, it has 4 columns, and I want to be able to click on "title" column and send request to "/film/{title}" where title is what I clicked on. I've used your line but it's not working- can you tell what have I done wrong?                     
                                                                                                                                         <td><<a th:href="|"/film/"+${film.title}|" th:text="${film.title}">Film</a></td>

Comment: did you try my solution ?

Comment: it worked now-- thank you!     <td><a th:href="|/film/${film.title}|" th:text="${film.title}">Film</a></td>